# I am trying to create a report using R Markdown. For the report i need a title page with logo. This is my YAML

Tags: r, r-markdown

This code creates two title pages. First page renders correctly. But i am getting second page also title, which has title, author and date on it. I would like to remove this second title page. Any help can i get please?

```yaml
---
title: |
  | My Organisation
  | 2023 Report
author: "My Name"
date: "2023-06-07"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{titling}
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
---
```

````latex
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat('
\\pagenumbering{gobble}
\\begin{titlingpage}
\\vspace*{0.5in} % Adjust the spacing as needed
\\centering
\\includegraphics[width=6in]{Logo_COLOUR.png}
\\maketitle
\\end{titlingpage}

\\newpage
\\thispagestyle{empty}
\\addtocounter{page}{-1}
')
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to set a header image for a quarto doc. That should just result in a single title page

```
number-sections: true
number-depth: 1
bibliography: refrencess.bib
format: 
  pdf: 
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
            \usepackage{fancyhdr}
            \pagestyle{fancy}
            \fancyhf{}
            \rhead{\includegraphics[width = .25\textwidth]{Logo_COLOUR.png}}
            \cfoot{\thepage}
```